# Send sensor information to processing

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, datalogging, processing-lang

I am currently working on an Arduino project where the Arduino will send data to a processing program via bluetooth and processing will draw the data. However, my code doesn't seem to work.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

int bluetoothTx = 1;
int bluetoothRx = 0;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup() {
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {    
  Serial.println("Hello");
}
```

And here is my Processing code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

void setup() {
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM42", 9600);
  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void serialEvent( Serial myPort) {
  String data = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  println(data);
}
```

I identified that the incoming port from the HC-05 module is "COM42" from my Bluetooth settings. I am expecting to see several "Hello" lines being printed on the processing console but this does not happen

Answer (score 1):

Your whole sending program is a complete mess, sorry to say:

First you create a SoftwareSerial port using the HardwareSerial pins. (Why on earth would you do that?)

Then you "begin" that SoftwareSerial port.

Finally you try and print `Hello` through the **HardwareSerial** port!

Either use SoftwareSerial **OR** use the hardware UART. You can't mix and match both. And since you are using the hardware UART pins, why even consider using SoftwareSerial?

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Hello");
}
```

**OR, to use *other pins than 0 and 1*:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int bluetoothTx = 2;
const int bluetoothRx = 3;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);

void setup() {
    bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {    
    bluetooth.println("Hello");
}
```

Comment: This worked! But can you please explain why it didn't work at the first place? Also, the modified code didn't work till after I modified the COM port to be the "outgoing" one as seen in my Bluetooth settings, why is that?

Comment: Before you had turned on the hot tap on the bath and were wondering why the toilet hadn't flushed. You had created and configured a software "bit banged" serial interface, but then proceeded to attempt to send the data down the unconfigured and disabled hardware UART.